# Create cloud texture using python

Tags: python

As part of a larger script, I am using the following to add a displacement modifier to each object:

```
displace_modifier = obj.modifiers.new(name="Displace.01", type='DISPLACE')
displace_modifier.strength = 10.0
tex = bpy.ops.texture.new("Displace.01", 'CLOUDS')
displace_modifier.texture = tex
```

and getting the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\make_stone_wall.py", line 267, in execute
    main(self, context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\make_stone_wall.py", line 131, in main
    tex = bpy.ops.texture.new("Displace.01", 'CLOUDS')
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 186, in __call__
    C_dict, C_exec, C_undo = BPyOpsSubModOp._parse_args(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 143, in _parse_args
    raise ValueError("1-3 args execution context is supported")
ValueError: 1-3 args execution context is supported

location: <unknown location>:-1

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I am pretty sure I am missing some of the arguments for bpy.ops.texture.new(...), but I haven't been able to find anything online to help me figure it out.

Does anyone know what I'm missing, here?

Answer (score 1):

Rookie mistake. I was calling bpy.ops.texture... instead of bpy.data.texture...